# java multithreading , Difference in child thread running time

Tags: java, multithreading, cmd

i ran a code `10 times` on `windows cmd line` and `every time` i got `same output`

[image]

i ran the `same code` on `ideone ,10 times` and each time i got `same output` as

[image]

My questions are :

- according to my code child thread must sleep for `500ms` and main thread for `1000ms` so i think that after main thread runs `once` , child thread runs `twice` but in `cmd output` , child ran `3 times` once and `1 time` other time. why?
- output is different on `ideone` and `cmd` ?

here is my code

```
class newthread extends Thread {

    newthread() {

    super("demo thread");

    System.out.println("child thread:"+this);

    start();}

    public void run(){

    try{

    for(int i=5;i>0;i--)  {

        System.out.println("child thread:"+i);

        Thread.sleep(500); }

       }

   catch(InterruptedException e){

        System.out.println("child thread interrupted");}

        System.out.println("child thread exiting");

       }

}

    class exthr{

       public static void main(String args[]){

         new newthread();

         try{

         for(int i=5;i>0;i--)    {

         System.out.println("main thread:"+i);

         Thread.sleep(1000);     }

            }

         catch(InterruptedException e){

         System.out.println("main thread interrupted ");     }

       System.out.println("main thread exiting");

       }

       }
```

Comment: Come on! Please format your code properly! If you want us to read it, it should be readable!

Comment: Also, please call it a _program_, not _a code_.  Programs, libraries, modules, classes, methods, etc. are all _things_.  Code is the _stuff_ of which all of those things are made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons of such a difference:

- It's system scheduler who gives CPU time to the threads and it's free to organize it as he likes. You cannot force it to give CPU to your thread with exact precision.
- When doing synchronization between threads you should not rely on `sleep`. This basically deactivates thread for a while, but there are no guarantees that it will awake immediately. If you want particular order you should use synchronization primitives like mutexes and condition variables.
- Most likely you have different hardware on your machine and on ideone server. Moreover ideone is most likely very loaded with other things, so fluctuation is bigger.

Answer (score 2):

So main sleeps for 1000 ms., and child sleeps twice for 500 ms. They should thus write to `System.out` **approximately** at the same time.

Sometimes the main thread comes before, and sometimes after. That depends on the precision of the clock, on the other threads running, on the choices of the thread scheduler, on whether the threads sleep exactly for the time they were told to sleep or a bit more, on the time elapsed between the main thread starting the child thread and the time the thread actually starts running, etc.

You can't expect a strict sequence of events unless you correctly synchronize the threads to make them wait for each other.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to assume that your program will resume immediately after timer runs out. This is not neccessarily the case on any machine, unless you are on a realtime system with control of all processes and priorities.
It would be likely, though, that on a machine with moderate load, the behaviour would be like the behaviour exhibited by ideone. Admittedly, it is odd that your windows machine generates the same output allways, but it does not change the fact that the only guarantee you have is that your thread will sleep for AT LEAST the time you specify, not AT MOST. You could include a timestamp in your output to verify this, if you want to.